# How do I add another field after saving entity metadata wrapper?

Tags: entities

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
function create_content($type,$content){
  $node = entity_create('node', array('type' => $type));
  $emw_node = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  $fields = field_info_instances("node",$type);
  foreach ($content as $field => $value){
    if (array_key_exists($field,$fields)){
      $type=field_info_field_by_id($fields[$field]['field_id'])['type'];
      if ($type=='link_field') {
        $emw_node->$field->url = $value;
      }
      else {
        $emw_node->$field = $value;
      }
    }
  }
  $emw_node->save();
  $id = $emw_node->getIdentifier();
  $emw_node->other_field = $id;
  $emw_node->save();
}
```

With the idea of copying the node id to another field. However, I get an error:

EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. Value at node(9999)->field_other_field: 9999. in EntityMetadataWrapper->set() (line 122 of /sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

How do I do this properly, preferably while still using an entity metadata wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be with your field format. If your field other_field is a text field check what text format is set for it in admin/structure/types/manage/your_content_type/fields. EG:
[image]

If it is different from the plain text format you have to assign an array as a value to your field. EG:

```
$emw_node->other_field = array('value' => $id, 'format' => 'filtered_html');
```

or just

`$emw_node->other_field = array('value' => $id);`

Comment: The thing is, all the fields affected by the line `$emw_node->$field = $value;` are text fields, and so is the other_field field. The content in `$content` for those fields arrives as strings, just like the result from `$id = $emw_node->getIdentifier();`. Nevertheless, I'm going to try your solution.

Comment: Your solution worked (to my surprise), I used `$emw_node->other_field = array('value' => $id);`. Now there remains the enigma of why in one case I can simply assign the value of a text field as a string and in the other case I need to wrap it in an array. All those fields are set to allow only one value.

Comment: As i have proposed in my answer check text format of your fields (plain text, full html etc.). Maybe it will help.

Comment: You're right. The other fields were set as plain text whereas other_field was set as token text.